# How to prevent to trap keystrokes in delphi

Tags: delphi, window, hook

I'm using this class ([link](https://github.com/JensBorrisholt/Hooks)) from Jens Borrisholt.
This class helps to monitor keyboard events.
but the problem is that all keystrokes is trapped inside my application and no characters appear on other programs!!!

```
  FHook := THookInstance<TLowLevelKeyboardHook>.CreateHook(Self);
  FHook.OnPreExecute := procedure(Hook: THook; var HookMsg: THookMessage)
    var
      LLKeyBoardHook: TLowLevelKeyboardHook;
      ScanCode: integer;
    begin
      LLKeyBoardHook := TLowLevelKeyboardHook(Hook);

      ScanCode := LLKeyBoardHook.KeyName.ScanCode;


      Caption := 'Got ya! Key [' + LLKeyBoardHook.KeyName.KeyExtName + '] blocked.';
      HookMsg.Result :=   LLKeyBoardHook.ThreadID;

    end;

  FHook.Active := true;
```

Comment: Does assigning non-zero value to `HookMsg.Result` cause interception of keystroke by your program, not only monitoring?

Comment: @MBo . I'v changed it but,nothing happened!

Comment: Does call of `CallNextHookEx` occur? (check with breakpoint)

Comment: @MBo. No it's not fired anywhere!

Comment: Return 0 to indicated handled.

Comment: @MikeDixon I tried both 0-1 but nothing happened!

Comment: @Ahmad Then this needs a [mcve].  If you return `HookMsg.Result := 0` then `CallNextHookEx` is called in the base `TCustomHook.HookProc`.  If that's not happening then you've done something else in your code that we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me!

I set `HookMsg.Result := 0;` inside `FHook.OnPostExecute`

```
FHook := THookInstance<TLowLevelKeyboardHook>.CreateHook(Self);
  FHook.OnPreExecute := procedure(Hook: THook; var HookMsg: THookMessage)
    var
      LLKeyBoardHook: TLowLevelKeyboardHook;
      ScanCode: integer;
    begin
      LLKeyBoardHook := TLowLevelKeyboardHook(Hook);

      if LLKeyBoardHook.LowLevelKeyStates.KeyState <> ksKeyDown then
        exit;

      ScanCode := LLKeyBoardHook.KeyName.ScanCode;

      if not(ScanCode in [VK_NUMPAD0 .. VK_NUMPAD9, VK_0 .. VK_9]) then
      begin
        Caption := 'Got ya! Key [' + LLKeyBoardHook.KeyName.KeyExtName + '] blocked.';
      end
      else
        Caption := '';

    end;


    FHook.OnPostExecute := procedure(Hook: THook; var HookMsg: THookMessage)
    begin
      HookMsg.Result := 0;
    end;
```